# Avalonia: Как привязать выбранный идентификатор роли из ComboBox к DataContext?

Tags: c#, avalonia

Есть window который содержит поля ввода данных(добавление нового user) и там есть combobox выбора роли
есть класс-модель для combobox.

```cs
public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

В combobox у меня отображается Title. Данные приходят из API. Вот AXAML код:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxRoles"
          Items="{Binding UserRole}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Id}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

он не работает у меня в datacontext `roleId` всегда `0`.
Мне нужно, чтобы в datacontext брался id роли, то есть в combobox был загружен список ролей из API и у них есть id, нужно чтобы id выбранного элемент в combobox передавался в datacontext

```xml
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxRoles"
          Items="{Binding UserRole}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Id}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

у меня написан такой AXAML код и такой c#:

```cs
private User _currentUser = new User();
this.DataContext = _currentUser;
```

я ожидала, что у выбранного элемента id будет передан в combobox при помощи этой строки `SelectedItem="{Binding Id}">` но в avalonia этого не происходит `roleid = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Items` надо биндить к коллекции, к свойству с элементами. А `SelectedItem` к свойству с одним из элементов этой коллекции. А `DataContext` должен указывать на экземпляр класса, где эти свойства находятся.

К примеру есть свойства в неком классе

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public UserRole[] Roles { get; set; }
    public UserRole SelectedRole { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда можно создать такой пример

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.Roles = new[]
{
    new UserRole { Id = 0, Title = "Администратор" },
    new UserRole { Id = 1, Title = "Пользователь" },
    new UserRole { Id = 2, Title = "Гость" }
};
DataContext = vm;
```

```xml
<ComboBox Items="{Binding Roles}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRole}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Если нужно управление поведением View из C#, например задавать `SelectedRole` програмно, то `ViewModel` и ее свойства должны реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([документация](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/change-notifications)).

Если нужно динамически с отслеживанием в UI изменять состав коллекции ролей, то коллекция должна быть наблюдаемая, например `ObservableCollection<T>` ([документация](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/tutorials/todo-list-app/creating-a-model-and-viewmodel)).

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ, это действительно помогло мне получить желаемый результат.